# Android 4.0 ICS turning HttpURLConnection GET requests into POST requests

Tags: java, android, google-reader, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Galaxy Nexus arrived today, and one of the first things I did was to load my app onto it so I could demonstrate it to my friends. Part of its functionality involves importing RSS Feeds from Google Reader. However, upon trying this, I was getting 405 Method Not Allowed errors.

This problem is Ice Cream Sandwich-specific. The code I've attached works fine on Gingerbread and Honeycomb. I've traced the error down to the moment the connection is made, when the GET request magically turns into a POST request.

```
/**
 * Get the authentication token from Google
 * @param auth The Auth Key generated in getAuth()
 * @return The authentication token
 */
private String getToken(String auth) {
    final String tokenAddress = "https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token";
    String response = "";
    URL tokenUrl;

    try {
        tokenUrl = new URL(tokenAddress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) tokenUrl.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlendcoded");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial method: " + connection.getRequestMethod()); // Still GET at this point

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected. Method is: " + connection.getRequestMethod());  // Has now turned into POST, causing the 405 error
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
            connection.disconnect();
            return response;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Something bad happened, response code was " + connection.getResponseCode()); // Error 405
            Log.d(TAG, "Method was " + connection.getRequestMethod()); // POST again
            Log.d(TAG, "Auth string was " + auth);
            e.printStackTrace();
            connection.disconnect();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Stuff
        Log.d(TAG, "Something bad happened.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there anything that could be causing this problem? Could this function be better coded to avoid this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This behaviour is described in [Android Developers: HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

> HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if
>   setDoOutput(true) has been called.

What's strange though is that this has not actually been the behaviour until 4.0, so I would imagine it's going to break many existing published apps.

There is more on this at [Android 4.0 turns GET into POST](http://webdiary.com/2011/12/14/ics-get-post/).

Answer (score 10):

Removing this line worked for me:

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

4.0 thinks with this line it should definitely be POST.

Comment: Thanks Fedor, Its work for me also. I have same problem with GET method. When I called GET method with setDoOutPut(true), I got the Http 405: Method Not Allowed message was return. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 8):

Get rid of this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlendcoded");
```

This tells the API this is a POST.

**UPDATE** on how it could be done via `HttpClient`:

```
String response = null;
HttpClient httpclient = null;
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(yourUrl);
    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        throw new Exception("Got HTTP " + statusCode 
            + " (" + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() + ')');
    }

    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // do some error processing here
} finally {
    if (httpclient != null) {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Removing that line makes no difference at all.

Comment: Ok, then you can also try to go with HttpClient.

Comment: @Michael Dodd: check the UPDATE section

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I do not set "Content-Type" property, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: EDIT: nvm, solved by @djh answer below (It will use POST if setDoOutput(true) has been called)

Answer (score 3):

This is one that got me -  basically by setting setDoOutput(true) it forces a POST request when you make the connection, **even if you specify this is a GET in the setRequestMethod**:

> HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if
>   setDoOutput(true) has been called. Other HTTP methods (OPTIONS, HEAD,
>   PUT, DELETE and TRACE) can be used with setRequestMethod(String).

This caught me a while back - very frustrating ...

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html and go to HTTP Methods heading

Answer (score 2):

I've found that pre-ICS one could get away with making a body-less POST without providing a Content-Length value, however post-ICS you must set Content-Length: 0.