# Android 4.0 Turns POST into GET

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a Gingerbread Android application that I'm porting to ICS.  This application communicates with a web server sending HTTP POST.  My application runs fine on Gingerbread.  However, I have been experiencing problems after porting it to ICS.  I found out that the POST requests my application is sending are actually changed to GET.

The funny thing is, Android actually reports that POST is indeed used.

```
URL oURL = new URL(sURL);

HttpURLConnection oHTTPConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(oURL.openConnection());
oHTTPConnection.setDoInput(true);
oHTTPConnection.setDoOutput(true);
oHTTPConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

// set headers...
int nResponse = oHTTPConnection.getResponseCode();

String sMethod = oHTTPConnection.getRequestMethod();  // Returns "POST"
```

However, the server would say otherwise.  I modified the web server application to check the request method it receives and then put this value in the response body it sends back to my Android application.  And what I receive on my Android application is "GET".

I have tried using HttpClient with HttpPost but I get the same issue.

As I mentioned, I didn't have this problem in Gingerbread.  Also, I've read from another thread here a similar (but opposite) problem that also only happens in ICS: [Android 4.0 ICS turning HttpURLConnection GET requests into POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187188/android-4-0-ics-turning-httpurlconnection-get-requests-into-post-requests).

Has anyone else experienced this?  Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Rai

Comment: Have you tried adding `oHTTPConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlendcoded");` ?

Comment: @MagnusJohansson yes, I've already tried that one, but, no luck.  :/  thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Try follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799198/372076

> I've found that pre-ICS one could get away with making a body-less
>   POST without providing a Content-Length value, however post-ICS you
>   must set Content-Length: 0.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work either.  I removed some parts of the code I posted above, but, in fact, I already have set Content-Length to 0.  I have been doing this since my Gingerbread version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you already found a fix for this, but i was having the same problem and just found a work around. In my case it was an issue on server's side with Apache's redirection. I was doing:

```
Url url = new Url("http://aaaa.bbbb.com/");
```

Changed to:

```
Url url = new Url("http://aaaa.bbbb.com/index.php");
```

Somehow the redirection was turning my POST into a GET with no parameters.

Comment: Redirection works by sending a header "Location: new url", and the http client follows this url using GET, regardless of the original request method. So it is not an issue of the server.

Comment: It can also happen when you POST a request to an http endpoint, and the server redirects to the https equivalent.